# Why does terraform fail with "An argument named "flow_log_destination_type" is not expected here"?

Tags: amazon-web-services, terraform

While I am using terraform to create vpc flow log module to s3 bucket then its throwing errors like:

```
  An argument named "flow_log_destination_type" is not expected here.
  An argument named "flow_log_destination_arn" is not expected here.
```

In the Terraform docs, I can see the details to be filled like `log_destination_type & log_destination_arn`,
and I found some docs on GitHub that exactly says the same code but while trying it's not working for me

The following error produced:

```
Error: Unsupported argument

  on main.tf line 52, in module "vpc_with_flow_logs_s3_bucket":
  52:   flow_log_destination_type = "s3"

An argument named "flow_log_destination_type" is not expected here.


Error: Unsupported argument

  on main.tf line 53, in module "vpc_with_flow_logs_s3_bucket":
  53:   flow_log_destination_arn  = "${aws_s3_bucket.terra-test2-lifecycle.arn}"

An argument named "flow_log_destination_arn" is not expected here.


Error: Unsupported argument

  on main.tf line 55, in module "vpc_with_flow_logs_s3_bucket":
  55:   vpc_flow_log_tags = {

An argument named "vpc_flow_log_tags" is not expected here.
```

Where I am doing wrong?

```
module "vpc" {
  source  = "terraform-aws-modules/vpc/aws"
  version = "2.33.0"
  # Interpolated from the workspace
  name = "${terraform.workspace}"
  cidr = var.vpc_cidr

  azs             = var.vpc_azs
  private_subnets = var.vpc_private_subnets
  public_subnets  = var.vpc_public_subnets

  enable_nat_gateway = var.vpc_enable_nat_gw
  single_nat_gateway = var.vpc_single_nat_gw

  public_subnet_tags = {
    Name = "${terraform.workspace}-public"
  }

  private_subnet_tags = {
    Name = "${terraform.workspace}-private"
  }

  tags = {
    Name = "${terraform.workspace}"
  }

  vpc_tags = {
    owner       = "PEDevOps"
    environment = "${terraform.workspace}"
    version     = "0.0.1"
    managedby   = "Terraform"
  }
}

module "vpc_with_flow_logs_s3_bucket" {
  source = "../../"
  log_destination_type = "s3"
  log_destination_arn  = "${aws_s3_bucket.terra-test2-lifecycle.arn}"

  vpc_flow_log_tags = {
    Name = "vpc-flow-logs-s3-bucket"
  }
  
}

resource "aws_s3_bucket" "terra-test-lifecycle" {
  bucket = "terra-test-lifecycle"
  acl    = "private"

  lifecycle_rule {
    id      = "log"
    enabled = true

    prefix = "log/"

    tags = {
      "rule"      = "log"
      "autoclean" = "true"
    }

    transition {
      days          = 30
      storage_class = "STANDARD_IA" # or "ONEZONE_IA"
    }

    expiration {
      days = 60
    }
  }
  lifecycle_rule {
    id      = "tmp"
    prefix  = "tmp/"
    enabled = true

    expiration {
      date = "2020-06-06"
    }
  }
}
```

Why does terraform fail with `An argument named "flow_log_destination_type" is not expected here`?

Comment: Could you edit your question to include the full error output that Terraform produced when you tried this? That's likely to help narrow down which part of this configuration the problem relates to.

Comment: Check if you have defined a variable named `flow_log_destination_type` in your module.

Comment: @MartinAtkins i have added the error thrown could you pls have a look and tell me the solution

Answer (score 11):

The module at "../../" does not declare any of  the **log_destination_type**, **log_destination_arn**, or **vpc_flow_log_tags** variables and Terraform considers it an error to assign to undeclared variables in a module block like this:

```
module "vpc_with_flow_logs_s3_bucket" {
  source = "../../"
  log_destination_type = "s3"
  log_destination_arn  = "${flow_log_destination_arn}"

  vpc_flow_log_tags = {
    Name = "vpc-flow-logs-s3-bucket"
  }
}
```

It's most likely that "../../" is the wrong source path for the **vpc_with_flow_logs_s3_bucket** module and  you should fix that. If you are in the source path for the module where this module block is declared and you run `cd ../../`, do you end up in the directory with the **vpc_with_flow_logs_s3_bucket** Terraform code? If not, then **source** is set incorrectly and you need to fix it.

If "../../" is the correct path, then you should add the missing variable declarations.

```
variable "log_destination_type" {
    type = string
}

variable "log_destination_arb" {
    type = string
}

variable "vpc_flow_log_tags" {
    type = map(string)
}
```

Answer (score 3):

I'll share another possible reason to this error.

Writing configuration block like this:

```
  scaling_config = {
    desired_size = 2
    max_size     = 2
    min_size     = 2
  }
```

Instead of (Notice the `=` Equal Sign):

```
  scaling_config {
    desired_size = 2
    max_size     = 2
    min_size     = 2
  }
```

Will give an error of `An argument named "scaling_config" is not expected here`.

---

(*) Notice that after the change, if the block type is really not supported the error title will be change from:

```
Error: Unsupported argument
```

To:

```
Error: Unsupported block type
```

With error message of:

```
Blocks of type "scaling_config" are not expected here.
```

Answer (score 2):

This error occurs if you are passing a variable that module is not expecting.

For e.g.

```
module "vpc_with_flow_logs_s3_bucket" {
  source = "../../"
  log_destination_type = "s3"
  log_destination_arn  = "${flow_log_destination_arn}"

  vpc_flow_log_tags = {
    Name = "vpc-flow-logs-s3-bucket"
  }

}
```

If you specify this it will throw an error if the variable flow_log_destination_arn is defined in main.tf and **not in variables.tf**

**source:**  ../../vpc_with_flow_logs_s3_bucket/main.tf

```
resource "aws_flow_log" "example" {
  iam_role_arn    = "${aws_iam_role.example.arn}"
  log_destination = "${aws_cloudwatch_log_group.example.arn}"
  traffic_type    = "ALL"
  vpc_id          = "${aws_vpc.example.id}"
}
```

Comment: Your statement "if the variable flow_log_destination_arn is defined in main.tf and not in variables.tf" is incorrect. The problem is assignment not definition and you need to be precise about which main.tf and variables.tf you mean since it is quite possible that there are multiple of both.